# Java JSON unit test pass with wrong value

Tags: java, jsonunit

I have the following function:

```
public class NorthboundApiLogicTest {

  @Test
  public void testIfParametersValuesAreCorrect() {
    String body = "{\"exception\":\"world\",\"error\":\"Not Found\",\"message\":\"hello\""
        + ",\"timestamp\":\"2020-01-07T12:26:48.334386Z\",\"status\":\"404\"}";
    try {
      JSONAssert.assertEquals("{message:hello, exception:world, status:403, error:Not Found}", 
          body, false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println(e);
    }
    System.out.println(body);
  }
}
```

I run this test with Maven, and strangely it pass successfully.

[image]

However, it should not, because I assert that `status=403` but the value is `404`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that JSONException thrown and you're in catch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's failing to *parse* the JSON before it even performs an assertion on the structure, and you're simply logging that via your `catch`.

```
catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println(e);
}
```

You need to let that exception be thrown from the method, or catch it and call `fail()` with an appropriate message.

And then fix the issue of your non-parseable JSON, of course!

Comment: Strange because according to this https://jsonlint.com my JSON is valid.

Comment: `{message:hello, exception:world, status:403, error:Not Found}` is not valid json